# Hybridauth LinkedIn - Problems to get full profile

Tags: php, linkedin-api, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

I created a LinkedIn app with just r_fullprofile grant, setted to Live instead of Development, and got my API Key and Secret Key.

In the config.php of hybridauth, I have:

```
"LinkedIn" => array(
"enabled" => true,
"keys" => array("key" => "ABC", "secret" => "DEF"),
"scope" => "r_fullprofile"
)
```

I don't have problems to go to the login/authorization screen, BUT... this screen ask me to grant for:
-Your Profile Overview, instead of Your Full Profile.
- Your Email Address
- Network Updates

I logged in and authorized anyway, was redirected to hybridauth again, to my domain. It shows me $adapter->getUserProfile() without problems, but it's just the basic profile.

I tried to use without success:

```
$adapter->api('/people/~');
```

or

```
$adapter->api('/people/~', 'post');
```

It returns:

```
LinkedIn Object([callback:protected] => [token:protected] => 
Array([oauth_token] => ... blah blah blah
```

**How can I get the full profile? I need to get the Experience, Skills, and Education data.**

Comment: According to [this](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting) it seems ok for the screen to show "YOUR PROFILE OVERVIEW" even when selecting fullprofile. Did you try without using Hybrid Auth?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Protected/extensions/hoauth/hybridauth/Hybrid/Thirdparty/LinkedIn/LinkedIn.php

and edit line 126.

Example :

const _URL_REQUEST                 = 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+rw_nus+r_network+r_fullprofile+r_contactinfo+w_messages';

Hope this helps.